# Corrupted BlackBerry SD card - partition table

Tags: data-recovery, fsck, testdisk

Thanks so much for the super interesting articles and discussions here. I've found myself with a 32GB micro SD card corrupted by my BB 9780.

Screenshot with some details is attached below. I have tried TestDisk normal, deep, boot sector analysis (backup is bad too) and rebuild (on a backup), but it won't find but a few files from the hundreds that were on there.

Next up I'd try to set the partition type to FAT32 and then to chksdk/dosfsck.

Any thoughts on this or how to best proceed?

[image]

Comment: Well placed windows so we can see most of the data we need. Good job! +1

Comment: Can't you format it and assign the space as fat ?

Comment: Thanks - did that, running dosfsck on it now as no files found.

Comment: dosfsck finished but still at 0 files - any suggestions? I used gparted to set to fat32, both testdisk and dosfsck didn't get any files back.